# Problem with encapsulated text in shaded node with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm working with the TikZ package and I noticed that even though I get a correct pdf file with this .tex file (found in this forum):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{ball} = [circle,shading=ball, ball color=red!80!white, minimum size=1cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [style=ball] {blah blah};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

if for example I change the colour from red to blue and I open the pdf file, keeping open the first one, there isn't the expected colour background, but if I close both the files and I open one of them the first one is correctly visualized, whereas the second is not...

Could someone tell me the reason of this problem?... and how to solve it...

PS: I'm working with MiKTeX and TeXnicCenter on Windows

Comment: There is only one pdf per tex file.  If you change the tex file then the pdf will change as well.  If you do unexpected things like open up another view of the same pdf file you might catch it sandwiched around changes to the tex file.  But that's temporary--eventually all views will reflect the updated tex file.  Is this at all relevant or do I completely misunderstand what you want to have happen?

Comment: I guess it's a problem with the reader. Perhaps it's the Adobe Reader, google `tikz shading adobe reader` (or combine with `bug`) gives some results. Try another pdf Reader. I can confirm that the Adobe Reader doesn't show the color but the TeXworks previewer does, on my system.

Comment: I'm working with Acrobat Reader 9.3 (whereas I do not have this problem with an older version...) and even if I open my pdf file got by LATEX after any pdf file I get this problem. This could be very unconfortable especially when you have to send your file to other people unless you decide to say sorry but first all you have to close all the other pdf files or you have to use a specific version of Acrobat Reader...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior with Adobe Reader 10.1.7 or Sumatra PDF 2.3.2. So if this was a bug in Adobe Reader it is fixed in the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX. Specifically, compile to DVI, convert to PS using dvips and then to pdf using ps2pdf. TikZ works this way as well.

When I tried that, I got the ball shading also with the Adobe Reader, in contrary to the pdfLaTeX way.

Comment: Thanks Stefan for your tips, I'm having some problem with the "dvi => ps" setting, but I noticed that even with the "LaTeX => PS => PDF" profile the problem has disappeared. Any other tips will be really appreciated. Thanks again.